# Homestead Laravel: The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, homestead

I am trying to install Laravel Homestead on my Windows 7 with Git Bash and I can't get passed through this step. When I do `vagrant up` I get this error all the time...after already searching 4 hours every single answer online and I am still getting the same error... Any suggestions ? thanks in advance!

I've tried different paths for map and nothing worked

```
map: C:/Users/Ris/Desktop/Code/
```

where I get the error:

vagrant up

```
there are errors of the configuration of this machine.Please fix 
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code
```

Homestead.yaml file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1


authorize: C:/Users/Ris/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys: 
    - C:/Users/Ris/.ssh/id_rsa


folders:
    - map: C:/Users/Ris/Desktop/Code/
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
```

Comment: Have you added the homestead box? 'vagrant box add laravel/homestead'

Comment: @AndrewCaulfield yes I did...

Answer (score -1):

Try

> homestead up

Instead of

> vagrant up

Homestead is an implementation of vagrant..

Comment: it didn't help , thanks though :(... I've reinstalled  vagrant box and it still can't get it...